# VS 2015 Cordova RemoteBuild on Mac Failed

Tags: ios, macos, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to build an IOS app with the new VS 2015 cordova addon. I have followed the insturctions on MSDN to install Remote build on my Mac, which seems to work ok.

however, when i tried to build a cordova app from VS 2015 on my PC, i m getting errors, which doesnt give me much info

these are error messages i got from my VS:

```
Error   /Users/[user]/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/487/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build    Command failed with exit code 2: {1}    D:\[path]\myproject\Error   1
```

the task runner output in VS:

```
> cmd.exe /c gulp -b "[project path]" --color --gulpfile "[path]\Gulpfile.js" index

[16:11:19] Starting 'copy-html'...

[16:11:19] Finished 'copy-html' after 4.28 ms

[16:11:21] Using gulpfile 
[path]Gulpfile.js

[16:11:21] Starting 'index'...

[16:11:21] Finished 'index' after 9.22 ms

Process terminated with code 0.
```

and this is what i got from my Mac:

```
New build request submitted:
/build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=5.1.1&cfg=debug&options=--device&loglevel=warn
{ 'accept-language': 'en-US',
  host: '[host]:3000',
  connection: 'close',
  'transfer-encoding': 'chunked' }

Build will be executed under: /Users/[user]/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/517

Saving build request payload to : /Users/[user]/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/517

Saved upload to /Users/[user]/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/517/upload_517.tgz

POST /cordova/build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=5.1.1&cfg=debug&options=--device&loglevel=warn 202 10663.718 ms - 664

GET /cordova/build/tasks/517 200 0.723 ms - 664

GET /cordova/build/tasks/517 200 2.269 ms - 664

GET /cordova/build/tasks/517 200 1.114 ms - 664

Extracted app contents from uploaded build request to /Users/[user]/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/517/cordovaApp. Requesting build.

Taking 517 as current build

GET /cordova/build/tasks/517 200 1.320 ms - 11505

GET /cordova/build/tasks/517 200 0.969 ms - 11512

Done with currentBuild. Checking for next build in queue.

GET /cordova/build/tasks/517 200 0.914 ms - 11770

GET /cordova/build/tasks/517/log 200 2.129 ms - -
```

now from observation, the VS build window shows the failed error message when the MAC terminal windows was displaying "Done with currentBuild. Checking for next build in queue."

I am new to MAC and IOS, so i dont know where to start fixing this problem. Did anyone have this kind of problem before?

thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

How are you running remotebuild on the mac side? i.e have you got --secure true or false?

Can you post your cordova settings from visual studio?

is there anything in that error file it refers to?

what version of xcode are you using?

Comment: secure is true, I couldnt set it to false as it will prompt error.

Comment: Have you got the secure setting off at both ends? In your cordova settings in visual studio as well as the remotebuild --secure false? It may not be the problem but I remember having problems with it myself so it's probably worth getting it working first without it on. Is there an error file at d:\wherever\myproject\error?

Answer (score 0):

Some times while remote building in VS you see errors or warnings but actually it's not that important .
You can just ignore it and open your xcode project in mac_user_name/remote_builds

Additionally check for plugins if they are match to ios platform or not .